# Angular UI Sortable Connected Lists added <li>s on second list vanishing after dropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying this code in my system

http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/894/

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
<ul ui:sortable="sortableOptions" class="connectedList" ng:model="list1">
    <li ng:repeat="item in list1" class="item">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul ui:sortable="sortableOptions" class="connectedList" ng:model="list2">
    <li ng:repeat="item in list2" class="item">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<div>{{list1}}</div>
<div>{{list2}}</div>
```

However, after drag-and-dropping an item from list1 to list2 the item+the rest of the elements of the list2 after the position at which the item was dropped are not displaying. However the complete list2 is displaying in the div where the list2 is binded.

eg `list1=[a,b,c,d]`

```
list2=[1,2,3,4]
```

i drag b from `list 1` to `list 2` and drop it after 2.

```
ul displaying(list1)
a
c
d

ul displaying(list2)
1
2


div displaying(list1)
a c d

div displaying(list2)
1 2 b 3 4
```

This problem is not happening in the fiddle, it is only happening in my system. I am not using CDNs to include `angular`, `angular-ui` but the files directly.
i have `j-query`, `jquery-ui`, `bootstrap` included in my code.

Please Help.